# Node red: share data between node

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am trying to share data between my node fucntions throw the use of context object, but seems like in this version it is not working:

```
My node version: 0.10.40
My node red version:  0.11.1
```

I can't update the node or the node red versions since I am using the embedded one in multitech mconduit gateway.. so I am stuck with this versions.

I tried the following `context.set("AE", AE)`, I got `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'set'`

and `global.set('AE',AE)`, I got `ReferenceError: global is not defined (line 7, col 1)`

Any ideas how to share data between node in this old version?

Thanks,
best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Node-RED that old there is only one type of context object (rather than the 3 seperate global, flow & context).

The *context* object has no getter/setter methods and is just a simple JavaScript object, so you set values as follows:

```
context.foo = "foo";
```

and get values like this:

```
var foo = context.foo;
```

There is still the concept of the global context, this is now just a child object of the *context* e.g. `context.global`

Check the yellow background boxes in the Node-RED documentation [here](https://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#storing-data)